# Is there a way to log any unexpected Exception occurred in ASP.NET page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, log4net

I'm using log4net to log expected Exception like following:

```
try {
   // some exception occurred
} catch (Exception ex)
{
   log.Error("Exception occurred!", ex);
}
```

The info will be written to a file or someplace I set. But for those which is not in try...catch block runtime exception, how can I record them totally whenever occurred?

Does log4net support it or is there any way to log them together? Thank you.

Comment: Unexpected... or unhandled? ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could subscribe to the global `Application_Error` event handler in your Global.asax where all unhandled exceptions will bubble up and you will have the possibility to log (and probably handle them).

For example:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();
    log.Error("Exception occurred!", exception);

    // TODO: optionally handle the exception here, for example display
    // some custom error page or something
}
```

Comment: Still have a question, after I start to record exception, it keeps to throw this exception: `2013-03-10 21:05:18,812 [14] ERROR ASP.global_asax [(null)] - Exception occurred!
System.Web.HttpException: File not exist
   in System.Web.StaticFileHandler.GetFileInfo(String virtualPathWithPathInfo, String physicalPath, HttpResponse response)
   in System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context) `
But I don't know who and where is calling and throwing this exception, how can I debug it? from the stacktrace I have no idea about it.

Comment: Looks like an HttpException. You could log the requested url: `Context.Request.Url`. This looks like some missing static file such as `favicon.ico` which is being requested from your browser.

Answer (score 5):

[ELMAH](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/) is your friend here - you *can* use it [with log4net](https://github.com/edwinf/log4net---ELMAH-Appender).

> ELMAH (Error Logging Modules and Handlers) is an application-wide error logging facility that is completely pluggable. It can be dynamically added to a running ASP.NET web application, or even all ASP.NET web applications on a machine, without any need for re-compilation or re-deployment.

You can get the appropriate package with configuration with nuget.

Comment: Also checkout [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) which has a plugin for [Elmah](http://elmah4glimpse.codeplex.com/).